# while loop, tkinter label cant display the output?

Tags: loops, tkinter, while-loop, label

### just testing out tkinter and python.. I would like to know why my tkinter hung up while running this code

```
enter code here : var_fan = tk.StringVar()
    label_fan = tk.Label(self, textvariable=var_fan, fg='red', bg='white') 
    label_fan.place(x=200, y=300)  
    
    xy = 0
    def fan_move():
        nonlocal xy
        xy = 2
        print(xy)
        
        
    def fan_circu():
        nonlocal xy
        while xy < 6 and xy > 1:
              
              sleep(2)
              xy +=1
              r = xy 
              var_fan.set(str(r))
              print(xy)         
              if xy == 6:
                  xy = 2
        
        self.after(10,fan_circu)
    
    fan_circu()
    
    btn_fan=tk.Button(self, text='start_fan', command= fan_move)
    btn_fan.place(x=300, y=410)
```

---

my objective here is to print out the syntax output in tkinter label. the output starts to increment once the button is push and before it reaches to a certain number it will go back to number 2 to repeat the count again one at a time.

however in the tkinter window it hungs up but at the output console its working and printing out the values.

thank you

regards,
jr

Comment: The infinite while loop will block the tkinter mainloop from handling pending events and updates.  That's why your program freezes.  Try changing the logic without the while loop.

Comment: To add to acw1668's comment, try looking at the `.after` method that all `tkinter` widgets have.